# Servicestack request header doesn't contains cookie

Tags: http, cookies, typescript, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack Authentication to authenticate, and using http to do so. This might be duplicate to my previous post, but this is another question. When I'm sending a post-request auth/logout the request header doesn't have session-id which doesn't logout the user on the other website.

How can I send a post logout request that log the user out from all the web site that he/she is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I send a post logout request that log the user out from all the web site that he/she is logged in?

In order for a User to be **logged in** they **need** to be sending ServiceStack's `ss-id/ss-pid` [Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids). If the HTTP Request doesn't contain the Session Cookies it's treated as an anonymous request and sending a logout request wont have any effect. But in most cases you would just use the **same HTTP Client** used to authenticate the user, to log them out as they'd automatically also send their Authenticated Session Cookies with every request.

Other ways you can send ServiceStack Session Ids is to [send Session Ids as HTTP Headers](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#use-http-headers-to-send-session-cookies) with the `X-` prefix, e.g:

```
X-ss-id: {sessionId}
X-ss-pid: {permSessionId}
X-ss-opts: ...
```

Or if you enable the `AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams` option in your AppHost, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams = true,
});
```

You can also send the Session Ids via QueryString, e.g:

```
/auth/logout?ss-id=...&ss-pid=...&ss-opts=...
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that angularJS didn't had withCredential = true as default.